# Function space and dimensionality

Tags: vector-spaces

The space $C[a,b]$, of continuous functions  $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ obviously
is a vector space, by pointwise addition and multiplication:

$(f+g)(x):=f(x)+g(x)$ and

$(\alpha \cdot f)(x)=\alpha f(x)$.

How does one go about establishing that it is an *infinite* dimensional vector space? In general given an arbitrary vector space, is there a standard way to find its dimension? (Or does one have to always fall back to Zorn's lemma?)

Answer (score 1):

You show hat for each $n\in\Bbb N$ there are $n$ linearly independent vectors. In this case, for each $n\in \Bbb N$ the functions
$$
\{1,x,\dots,x^{n-1}\}
$$
are linearly independent.

Comment: This shows that it cannot exists a finite set of functions that span $C[a,b]$?

Comment: Yes, this is a consequence of the fact that $C[a,b]$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Without an inner product, how can I establish that $\{1,x,\dots, x^{n-1}\}$ are linearly independent? Fundamental theorem of algebra?

Comment: If $c_1+c_2x+\dots+c_nx^{n-1}=0$ for all $x$, then $c_1=\dots c_n=0$. This is because a non zero polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ zeros.

Comment: Thanks Julian, can you briefly also elaborate on how your answer is a consequence of infinite dimensionality?

Comment: Any generating set contains a basis (no need of axiom of choice in the finite case.) If there were a finite generating set the dimension would be at most the cardinality of the generating set, which is finite.